# Telescoping recursive term ${D(h) = D(h-2)+1}$

Tags: algorithms, recursion, trees, recursive-algorithms

In the context of Computer Science, I am trying to calculate the maximum depth difference between leaf nodes in any existing AVL-Trees of height $h$. I don't think any knowledge of AVL trees is needed, since the following terms are the stand-alone mathematical relations resulting from them.

After some reflections, the recursive term resulting of this is the following ($D(h)$ being the maximum depth difference for any possible AVL tree of height $h$):

$D(h=2)=0, D(h=3)=1$

$D(h) = \max (D(h-1), D(h-2)+1) \quad\forall h\geq4$

This is then simplified to:

$D(h) = D(h-2)+1 \quad\forall h\geq4$

**Question 1:** How can one assume this simplification? I believe somewhere I read something about monotone growth in it, but since there's only a recursive relation towards two terms before, there's no apparent connection between $D(h-1)$ and $D(h-2)$.

We now use telescoping to arrive at the following:

$D(h) = D(h-2)+1 = ... = D(h-2k) + k$

**Question 2:**
How do I understand what is the condition of k, to continue telescoping until I arrive at a solution for $D(h)$?

**Question 3:** My intuition tells me there's going to be an even/odd distinction. How would one approach these kind of recursions for the general case of above?

$D(h) = D(h-p) + 1 \qquad \forall h\geq p$

having all the base cases:
$D(0),D(1),...,D(p-1)$

Comment: **Question 1** may be by induction: for $h\ge4$, let $P(h)$ be the statement $$D(h-2) \le D(h-1) \le D(h-2)+1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1** may be by induction: for $h\ge4$, let $P(h)$ be the statement $$D(h-2) \le D(h-1) \le D(h-2)+1$$

For $h=4$, check that

$$D(2) \le D(3) \le D(2)+1$$

Assume $P(k)$ is true for some $k\ge 4$:

$$D(k-2) \le D(k-1) \le D(k-2)+1$$

Then for $h=k+1$ (which compares $D(k-1)$ and $D(k)$),

$$\begin{align*}
D(k) &= \max\{D(k-1), D(k-2)+1\}\\
&\ge D(k-1) \tag 1\\
D(k) &= D(k-2)+1\\
&\le D(k-1) + 1 \tag2
\end{align*}$$

From inequalities $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$D(k-1) \le D(k) \le D(k-1)+1$$

So by mathematical induction, $\forall h\ge 4$, $P(h)$ is true and particularly $D(h-1) \le D(h-2)+1$. So

$$D(h) = D(h-2) + 1 \quad \forall h\ge 4$$

---

**Question 2** and **3** are usually by iterating enough times and observing the pattern.

$$\begin{align*}
D(h) &= D(h-2) + 1\\
&= (D(h-4) + 1) + 1 &&= D(h-4) + 2\\
&= (D(h-6) + 1) + 2 &&= D(h-6) + 3\\
&= (D(h-8) + 1) + 3 &&= D(h-\underbrace{8}_{2\cdot 4}) + 4\\
&= \vdots\\
&= D(h-2k) + k\\
\end{align*}$$

Then pick $k$ such that the argument $h-2k$ is $2$ or $3$, depending on the parity of $h$,

$$\begin{align*}
h-2k &= \begin{cases}
2, &h\text{ is even}\\
3, &h\text{ is odd}\\
\end{cases}\\
k &= \frac{h-\begin{cases}
2, &h\text{ is even}\\
3, &h\text{ is odd}\\
\end{cases}}2\\
D(h-2k) &= \begin{cases}
0, &h\text{ is even}\\
1, &h\text{ is odd}\\
\end{cases}\\
D(h) &= D(h-2k) + k\\
&= \frac{h + 2\cdot \left(\begin{cases}
0, &h\text{ is even}\\
1, &h\text{ is odd}\\
\end{cases}\right) - \left(\begin{cases}
2, &h\text{ is even}\\
3, &h\text{ is odd}\\
\end{cases}\right)} 2\\
&= \frac{h - 1 - \begin{cases}
1, &h\text{ is even}\\
0, &h\text{ is odd}\\
\end{cases}} 2\\
&= \frac{h - 1 - ((h-1)\bmod 2)}{2}\\
&= \left\lfloor\frac {h-1}2 \right\rfloor
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Beautiful. Greatly appreciated peterwhy!